# Save environment variable from json output in postman function

Tags: json, rest, postman

I have output data like:

```
{
"dbflash:db-files": {
    "db-file": [
        {
            "usageStatus": "Backup",
            "dbFileName": "DB_1710013320170619041443",
        },
        {
            "usageStatus": "Current",
            "dbFileName": "DB_1710013320170619111647",
        }
    ]
}
}
```

For which i need to set environment variable for backupDbFile and currentDbFile

I have written iterator for that, but because of key "dbflash:db-files" and "db-file" it is showing me syntax error.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
jsonData.dbflash:dbfiles.db-file.forEach(function(entry) { 
if (entry.usageStatus === 'Current') {
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("currentDb", JSON.stringify(entry.dbFileName));   
}
if (entry.usageStatus === 'Backup') {
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("backupDb", JSON.stringify(entry.dbFileName));   
}
});
```

Tried using quotes also but that too is not working

```
jsonData.'dbflash:dbfiles'.'db-file'.forEach(function(entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Square bracket notation `jsonData["dbflash:db-file"]` rather than dot notation will work.
Dot notation gives syntax error when you try to access invalid JSON keys.

Here is the link:
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3185